# Kernel Update uname showing wrong version

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, updates

I recently got a new server. Freshly installed 16.04. I noticed the kernel running is 2.6.32. So I wanted to update it.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic
```

Now I have this version: *4.4.0-21.37*

I also had to install grub to use *update-grub*.

*dpkg --list* shows me only linux-headers/images of *4.4.0-21.37*.

Also *update-grub* found kernels of that version.

But when I use uname it still tells me this

```
Linux london 2.6.32-042stab113.21 #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 11:05:25 MSK 2016 x86_64 x86
```

Yes I did reboot a couple times. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: The regular way of applying updates is to run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: why the `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic` ? Should have been as stated by AlexP. Redo it, it should go.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I used apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade as well and it installed 4.4. But still showing 2.6

Comment: You're using a VPS and the kernel you see is the host's. Nothing Ubuntu can do about it. If you want a newer kernel, contact your host.